# How to adapt Xib views and buttons to fit all devices using Auto layout and contraints

Tags: xcode, uibutton, autolayout, interface-builder, constraints

I'm going to show you an image that contains my first `UIViewController` presented in Interface Builder (using the `600x600 Any/Any View`).

[MainViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRtT5.png)

For now, just look at the `UIButton` with the `C` label and the Play button.  I added `Align center x to: horizontal` constraints to both.  When I preview what I have (forgetting about the other views and buttons you see), the 2 buttons are centered properly.  However, when I switch different device sizes, they do not change size...which makes sense.

What I want is for a way to make those 2 buttons stay proportionally circular and centered on the superview, but adapt their size and Y-position depending on the device size.  What constraints would I need to attach in order for that to work?  I don't want the buttons to be stuck in the spots you see in the image, I want them to adapt to the device size.

To talk about this further.  The game 'Color Switch' does not appear to use constraints in terms of having any view/image/button/label constrained to a certain y or x position.  Going from a 5c to a 6s, it's like looking at a blown up version of the game.  The buttons and title label at the top are not constrained to the same y position on each device.

Comment: Oh sorry, just to clarify.  Each circle you see on the image I uploaded is an independent `IBOutlet UIButton` property.  Originally, I calculated all necessary x-y coordinates to look good on my iPhone 5c.  So for that middle Play button, I took it's width / 2, and subtracted it from screen width / 2 to make it center. If I just ran the original code without the Xib attempting to construct constraints, would all the buttons sort of scale up to match the new screen?

Comment: Also, you know how there's an option in the Interface Builder to switch from Any/Any to Compact/Regular, etc.?  Could I just create the image I uploaded, in each device width/height scenario?  Ex: for the iPad option, just make all my `UIImages` and `UIButtons` larger to fit the screen.  I have @2x and @3x versions of my .png files so the device should compensate.  My app will not be incorporating device rotation, so that knocks off a couple scenarios as well.  What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You could create constraints to center the buttons to the top-level view and then make their width proportional to the view width.  Then on a larger screen, the buttons will be larger and on a smaller screen, they will be smaller.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Jerry.  Unfortunately I have tried that, but in terms of the buttons positions in the larger screens, they are constrained to the y-positions from the top-level view.  If there is a way to have the y-position adapt to the new screens, along with the width and height, then I'd look into it.  But I haven't found that solution yet

Comment: Delete all the constraints and start with just two, one to center horizontally and one to center vertically.